# How would I set the status of an agent from "Missed" to "Available" in Amazon Connect?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-connect

we are using Amazon Connect and we are running into an issue.
On the service-desk, we have a "standby shift", this means the user that is in that queue/shift is the only on-call. However, if he/she misses said call. They are stuck in the "Missed" state within the Connect CCP. I already tried the custom CCP method, however this does not fit our requirements yet.

Our second option is making a lambda that gets executed on a missed call (Right before the disconnect of a user) to remove the "Missed" state and set it on "Available". This is what I tried to do so:

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
var connect = new AWS.Connect();
let agentARN = event['Details']['Parameters']['agent'];


var params = {
  AgentStatusId: 'Available', 
  InstanceId: 'arn:aws:connect:eu-central-1:ID:ARN', 
  UserId: agentARN 
};

let errors;

connect.putUserStatus(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) errors = err.stack; // an error occurred
  else     errors = data;           // successful response
});

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: errors
    };
    return response;
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: You would need another mechanism to remove the caller from the queue, before making the agent available again. Otherwise, the agent will have another missed call, potentially infinitely.