# In Amazon Connect, how can you turn off a perpetual stream of Agent Event HEART_BEATs with MISSED state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

See [similar stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73717536/how-would-i-set-the-status-of-an-agent-from-missed-to-available-in-amazon-co) on this matter.

I am receiving a perpetual stream of Agent Events -- all HEART_BEATs -- in which the `State` is `MISSED`.  Based on cited article, it sounds like an Agent missed an incoming call, and never was able to reset his status to `Available`.

How can we avoid this?  I am picturing a production-scenario where -- over time -- thousands of these HEART_BEATs clog our data pipes.  Surely Amazon Connect has some kind of internal resolution to this circumstance.

QUESTION: how can you turn off a perpetual stream of Agent Event HEART_BEATs with MISSED state?